# Put a vector to base of Vectors in Rational number

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, rational-numbers

Base:
$$((1,0,2), (2,1,1), (1,1,1)) $$
I found out, all of vectors are linear independent. So it creates base of $\mathbb Q^3$. So I need to put this vector:
$$(3,2,-3) $$
And put this vector to the base. How can I put in? I know I can have only 3 vectors. So can I just replace vectors? Or there is some methods to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the matrix $A$ which has given basis vectors as column and solve the system

$$Ax=\begin{pmatrix}3\\2\\-3\end{pmatrix}$$

which has an unique solution.